# How to combine mdframed and tabu

Tags: mdframed, tabu

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabu}

\mdfdefinestyle{graybox}{
    innertopmargin=2mm,%
    innerbottommargin=2mm,%
    roundcorner=2mm,%
    backgroundcolor=gray!20}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[style=graybox]
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {@{}Xcrrr@{}}
    \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Price} & \textbf{Qty} & \textbf{Total} 
\end{tabu}
\end{mdframed}
\vskip - \baselineskip
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {@{}Xcrrr@{}}
    Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820
\end{tabu}


\end{document}
```

The problem is obvious:

[image]

I think this must be a single table, and mdframed should be used just for the first row, not the whole table. But how? Maybe mdframed is not the right solution for this?

Desired output:

[image]

UPDATE: for long tables see [longtabu + rounded box in the header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201419/longtabu-rounded-box-in-the-header)

Comment: Does moving `\end{mdframed}` to be _after_ `\end{tabu}` do what you want?  I am not exactly sure what the desired outcome is:  `\begin{mdframed}[style=graybox]
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {@{}Xcrrr@{}}
    \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Price} & \textbf{Qty} & \textbf{Total} \\
    Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820
\end{tabu}
\end{mdframed}`

Comment: Desired outcome is that columns are aligned under each other. E.g. date value is under the "Date" column. But the frame should only show up in the first row (heading). Not the others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way in which you are using it, the problem is with the column widths. Further, I would prefer `tcolorbox` over `mdframed`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol,array}
\usepackage{tabu}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{%
    enhanced jigsaw,
    boxrule=0.5pt,
    left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0mm,bottom=0mm, 
    colback = gray!20,
    arc=2mm,
}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{1cm}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {@{\,}XC{2cm}RRR@{}}
    \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Price} & \textbf{Qty} & \textbf{Total}
\end{tabu}%
\end{mybox}%
\vskip-0.55\baselineskip
\noindent
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {XC{2cm}C{1cm}C{1cm}C{1cm}@{}}
    Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820
\end{tabu}
```

[image]

```
\end{document}
```

Here is an example to show the advantage of `tcolorbox` in which we use only one table.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tcbset{enhanced jigsaw,
        boxrule=0pt,
        fonttitle=\bfseries\large,
        fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
        colback=white,colframe=white,
        overlay={
          \draw[preaction={fill=gray!40},rounded corners=2mm,thick]
               (frame.north west) rectangle
                     ($(frame.north east) + (0,-1.25\baselineskip)$);
    }
}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{1cm}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx*={\arrayrulewidth0mm}{XC{2cm}RRR}]
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Price} & \textbf{Qty} & \textbf{Total}\\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For auto sized columns redefine `C` and `R` columns

```
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
```

Or even better

```
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\hsize=0.5\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=0.5\hsize}X}
```

Comment: Yes, the question was about column widths. This was a MWE. I wanted a solution that works with multiple auto sized columns. So I think using two tables will never work in general. But in this particular case it does. BTW what is the advantage of using tcolorbox instead of mdframed?

Comment: @nagylzs See the update for the advantages ;-)

Comment: This is now almost perfect. To be honest, I don't understand the tabularx*= part. Will this work with longtabu as well? Unfortunately, there will (probably) be lots of rows that don't fit onto a single page.

Comment: @nagylzs This may be a worth candidate for a new question. Please ask new one.

Comment: New question asked. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201419/longtabu-rounded-box-in-the-header