# longtabu + rounded box in the header

Tags: tcolorbox, longtabu

This question is a continuation of [How to combine mdframed and tabu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201387/how-to-combine-mdframed-and-tabu)

I have lots of rows and it won't work with tabluarx. I would like to present this rounded box around the heading rows of a longtable or longtabu.

Example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\Repeat}[2]{% \repeat already defined
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#1}{#2}
}

\tcbset{enhanced jigsaw,
        boxrule=0pt,
        fonttitle=\bfseries\large,
        fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
        colback=white,colframe=white,
        overlay={
          \draw[preaction={fill=gray!40},rounded corners=2mm,thick]
               (frame.north west) rectangle
                     ($(frame.north east) + (0,-1.25\baselineskip)$);
    }
}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{1cm}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx*={\arrayrulewidth0mm}{XC{2cm}RRR}]
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Price} & \textbf{Qty} & \textbf{Total}\\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
LAST &  9999-99-99 & 999 & 9 & 99999 \\

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I need to use a longtable or a longtabu here. And tcolorbox does not work together with longtable or longtabu. I'm now thinking about drawing the background of the header cells with tikz, but not sure how.

UPDATE:

```
\begin{longtabu} {cc}
\boxedheader{ \textbf{D1} & \textbf{D2} }
2014-01-01 & 2014-01-01 \\
2014-01-01 & 2014-01-01 \\
\end{longtabu}
```

Result:

[image]

Possible workaround is to create fake columns with invisible content:

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
\begin{longtabu} {lcp{12pt}cr}
\boxedheader{ & \textbf{D1} & & \textbf{D2} & }
& 2014-01-01 & & 2014-01-01 & \\
& 2014-01-01 & & 2014-01-01 & \\
\end{longtabu}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could adapt `tcolorbox` to be used together with `longtabu`. But if the the table header should be boxed only, I would suggest to use a pure `tikz` solution (plus `tikzmark`):

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,longtable,tabu}
\usepackage{colortbl,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcounter{headercounter}

\newcommand{\boxedheader}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{headercounter}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \path[thick,rounded corners=2mm,draw=black,fill=gray!40!white,overlay]
    (-0.2,-0.25\baselineskip) rectangle ([xshift=2mm,yshift=0.75\baselineskip]pic cs:tableright\roman{headercounter});
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  #1
  \tikzmark{tableright\roman{headercounter}}\\%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {@{}Xcrrr@{}}
\boxedheader{\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Price} & \textbf{Qty} & \textbf{Total}}
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
Some name here &  2014-01-01 & 420 & 2 & 820 \\
LAST &  9999-99-99 & 999 & 9 & 99999 \\
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the first parameter is not `X`, an absoult positioning without `\baselineskip` seems to be needed:

```
\newcommand{\boxedheader}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{headercounter}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \path[thick,rounded corners=2mm,draw=black,fill=gray!40!white,overlay]
    (-0.2,-0.1) rectangle ([xshift=2mm,yshift=3mm]pic cs:tableright\roman{headercounter});
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  #1
  \tikzmark{tableright\roman{headercounter}}\\%
}
```

Comment: I'm excited about this solution. Please see the update in the question.

Comment: Updated the question. I'll be accepting this solution but will wait 24 hours because using these hand typed labels for \boxedheader invocations is very clumsy. There must be a workaround.

Comment: @nagylzs See my updated answer. It should work now for many tables (compiling twice). By the way: if it's sure that all tables have `\textwidth`, there would be an easier solution with hardcoding the table head width (omitting the `tikzmark`).

Comment: @nagylzs I'm glad I could help :-)

Comment: Another problem. Please see updated question.

Comment: @nagylzs I've added an alternative which works for `l` and `c` also.

Comment: Produces http://i.stack.imgur.com/or2Zm.jpg - does not seem to be right. The header box is aligned to the text in the header, and not to the column of the table.

Comment: @nagylzs It is right, but it may be not nice... This answer code boxes the header not the table (or table width). I think there is no global answer which works in all thinkable situations.

Comment: All right. Probably I'll be using an invisible element, that should solve this problem too.

Comment: Adding an invisible column on each side of the table works in every possible case I can think of! :-)